# How to invoke guava Predicate without filter?

Tags: java, guava, predicate

I read this article about guava Predicates

http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2010/10/googole-guava-v07-examples.html

note point `Predicates / Functions`

There are is written:

> The invocation would be (returns boolean):
>
> `Predicates.in(users).apply(shouldNotHaveDigitsInLoginPredicate);`

I cannot make so.

my IDE writes that method apply cannot be applyed to this type.

Please, help me.

Comment: This is quite an old article. Rather refer to up-to-date sources (Guava changes quite a lot and the changes are sometimes not compatible since methods are removed on a regular basis.) The official doc is quite good: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog entry does not make sense. Look at the API for [`Predicates`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html):

`Predicates.in(users)` creates a [`Predicate`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) of the generic type `User`, i.e. `Predicate<User>`. This predicate takes an argument of type `User` in its `Predicate#apply(T)` method. The class `ShouldNotHaveDigitsInLoginPredicate` implements `Predicate<User>` itself and is therefore **not** of type `User`. Therefore, your IDE warns you of a type mismatch.

What you can do is:

```
User user = getSomeUser();
Predicates.and(Predicates.in(users), new ShouldNotHaveDigitsInLoginPredicate())
    .apply(user);
```

Comment: *shouldNotHaveDigitsInLoginPredicate* (starts from small s) - what is it?

Comment: I just assumed it was a variable pointing to an instance of `ShouldNotHaveDigitsInLoginPredicate`. Maybe it is just a typo in the blog.

Comment: it is true) I think so before but I made something wrong and had compile errors